# What is a good deed?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, word-request

Suppose I wanted to talk about good deeds. Generally this means acts done by someone for selfless reasons, solely to benefit others.

For a literal translation I could go with *bona facta*, but the phrase in English is very idiomatic, and you seldom see the word "deed" otherwise. (Similarly, you seldom hear of "bad deeds".)

Is there a better way to express this concept in Latin? If not, what's the closest equivalent? I'm mainly interested in Classical Latin, but an Ecclesiastic equivalent would also be interesting (and probably easier to find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[beneficium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DB%3Aentry%20group%3D9%3Aentry%3Dbeneficium) -i, pl. -a** (also benificium, and beneficum) a good deed, a well-intentioned act; benefaction, kindness, favor, benefit, service

> beneficium dare, accipere  (Cicero, Sallust)
>   “pro maleficio beneficium reddere,” Terence

**[maleficium -i](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DM%3Aentry%20group%3D6%3Aentry%3Dmaleficium), pl. -a** a bad deed,  ill-intentioned act, an evil deed, misdeed, wickedness, offence, crime.

> “committere / admittere maleficium,"  Cicero

Comment: These are good words, but do you have citations for where they were used, or what exactly they meant?

Comment: +1 Good ones! But my impression (I could be wrong) is that _beneficium_ implies some kind of material effect on others that not all good deeds have. E.g. is telling the truth a good deed? Is it a beneficium?

Answer (score 5):

For what its worth, St. Thomas Aquinas uses the following:

- For *deed*, **actus** and **actio**, the latter seeming preferred, at least as per [*ST I-II, Q. 18, Art. 1*](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/sth2006.html#34256).
- For *good*, **bonum/-a**, and for *bad*, **malum/-a**.

**Actiones** are said by St. Thomas both **bonae** and **malae**, depending on... well, I won't spoil the book for you. Examples:

> Ergo **actiones** humanae secundum circumstantias sunt **bonae** vel **malae** *(Ibid., a. 3 s. c.)*
>   Non ergo secundum finem dicitur **actio** **bona** vel **mala**. *(Ibid., a. 4 arg. 2*

But I fail to quickly find a place where an *actio* is said *bona* or *mala* without the mediation of the verb *esse*. Instead, I found a plain *actus bonus* as the subject of a sentence:

> Omnis **actus bonus** concordat rationi et legi aeternae *(Ibid., q. 21 a. 1 co.)*

*Actus bonus* is also used by Aquinas in *De Malo*, and apparently by [Okham](https://books.google.cl/books?id=qNLkfTJaq3QC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=%22actus%20bonus%22&source=bl&ots=zcq90OCCeA&sig=bLbPW0ignFbsLv5lZBt-g-fWpVY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV6anmp9ncAhWJCpAKHc1KDKcQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22actus%20bonus%22&f=false).

---

**Actus** meaning deed, as for I could research quickly, doesn't seem to be Classical (its meanings, according to L&S being [much more specific](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dactus2)). Among the words listed by L&S meaning *deed* I've been able to find, these are the relative maximum frequencies:

- **[Actum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=actum&lang=la)**: 14K, with a lot of law specific meanings increasing the number
- **[Factum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=factum&lang=la)**: 25K, also mixed with other meanings

**Actio** gives 1.6K and is not listed as meaning *deed*, but the [dictionary entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dactio) includes *act* and *action* among its meanings.

Unfortunately, after a quick search, I haven't been able to find neither *acta* nor *facta* qualified as good or bad in Classical texts.

---

**Conclusion**: after this quick (and blatantly non-exhaustive) research, I'd go for **actus bonus** in ecclesiastical/medieval Latin. As for classical Latin, I'm inclined to think there is no closed expression and a **circumlocution** is to be preferred (e.g., avoid talking about good deeds, by using things like *to act well*, *do good*, etc., not sure witch one, though)